# Anyone know how to use the FBNativeAdBridgeCallback function in audience network unity

Tags: c#, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-audience-network

Can anyone please tell me how to use the FBNativeAdBridgeCallback function? i basically want to know when the images are finished loaded so that i can display them. . else i have a native banner flying around with empty values until Facebook has finished loading them. and it looks really ugly if each image/text loads in one at a time.

Its just the basic native ads sample script, i tried using IResult like one does with the login, but that makes it red. there is no documentation on this on the internet, not even on the Facebook developer site, i can't find the api at all.

Can anyone please explain to me how to use it in the script provided below?

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using AudienceNetwork;

[RequireComponent (typeof(CanvasRenderer))]
[RequireComponent (typeof(RectTransform))]
public class NativeAdTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private NativeAd nativeAd;

    // UI elements in scene
    [Header("Text:")]
    public Text
        title;
    public Text socialContext;
    [Header("Images:")]
    public Image
        coverImage;
    public Image iconImage;
    [Header("Buttons:")]
    public Text
        callToAction;
    public Button callToActionButton;

    public GameObject hide;

    void Awake ()
    {
        // Create a native ad request with a unique placement ID (generate your own on the Facebook app settings).
        // Use different ID for each ad placement in your app.
        NativeAd nativeAd = new AudienceNetwork.NativeAd ("your placement id");
        this.nativeAd = nativeAd;

        // Wire up GameObject with the native ad; the specified buttons will be clickable.
        nativeAd.RegisterGameObjectForImpression (gameObject, new Button[] { callToActionButton });

        // Set delegates to get notified on changes or when the user interacts with the ad.
        nativeAd.NativeAdDidLoad = (delegate() {
            Debug.Log ("Native ad loaded.");
            Debug.Log ("Loading images...");
            // Use helper methods to load images from native ad URLs
            StartCoroutine (nativeAd.LoadIconImage (nativeAd.IconImageURL));
            StartCoroutine (nativeAd.LoadCoverImage (nativeAd.CoverImageURL));
            Debug.Log ("Images loaded.");
            title.text = nativeAd.Title;
            socialContext.text = nativeAd.SocialContext;
            callToAction.text = nativeAd.CallToAction;
            Debug.Log ("Native ad Luke.");
        //  hide.SetActive(false);
            //FBNativeAdBridgeCallback


        });
        nativeAd.NativeAdDidFailWithError = (delegate(string error) {
            Debug.Log ("Native ad failed to load with error: " + error);
        });
        nativeAd.NativeAdWillLogImpression = (delegate() {
            Debug.Log ("Native ad logged impression.");
        });
        nativeAd.NativeAdDidClick = (delegate() {
            Debug.Log ("Native ad clicked.");
        });



        // Initiate a request to load an ad.
        nativeAd.LoadAd ();
        //nativeAd.nat
    }

    void OnGUI ()
    {
        // Update GUI from native ad
        coverImage.sprite = nativeAd.CoverImage;
        iconImage.sprite = nativeAd.IconImage;
    }

    void OnDestroy ()
    {
        // Dispose of native ad when the scene is destroyed
        if (this.nativeAd) {
            this.nativeAd.Dispose ();
        }
        Debug.Log ("NativeAdTest was destroyed!");
    }

//  void FBNativeAdBridgeCallback(IResult result)
//  {
//      
//  }

}
```

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: what do you mean by "the images are finished loaded"? so that the banner ad is loaded?

Comment: @NikaKasradze i want to know when the public objects contain the actual Values. else i have a native banner flying around with empty values until Facebook has finished loading them. and it looks really ugly if each image/text loads in one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

`AdView` does not allow you to define a customized listener from `FBNativeAdBridgeCallback()`. `AdView` already provided 5 callbacks includes `NativeAdDidLoad()`.

The solution to your question is to hide the ad first, then after you received the `NativeAdDidLoad()` and finished loading images, bring the ad to front and make it visible. There is no need to create a new `FBNativeAdBridgeCallback()`.

Comment: the problem is that the Coroutine starts inside NativeAdDidLoad() so when i make my adView available the Coroutine is still busy loading the images even after i make it available after the             Debug.Log ("Native ad Luke.") is shown - one can still see the cover image loading in and then the button name change and so on... so how do i get feedback when i can display the advert?